# Magento2:custom module add new form action after not save data

Tags: module, backend, save, magento-2.1.9

I have create new custom module click add new form after data fill up than save not working but if in existing  record edit after save working please let me know hows problem?

Comment: Please add your code here whatever you have tried.

Comment: I have just set auto increment in id no one change in code

Answer (score 0):

In database table after set auto increment in id my issue resolved.